# Tracert's last hop is showing the URL of a shared host - Why?

Tags: vps, shared-hosting, networking

I'm running multiple websites on a shared hosting service (sharing the one IP) that is also hosting many other websites out of my control. Doing a Bing 'ip:' search shows all these sites. There's quite a lot.

When I run a Tracert on these websites they all show the last hop's URL as one of the sites on the shared host. I'm wondering why it's showing that one URL in particular?

Is it possible to change which vhost gets shown as the last hop?

Answer (score 2):

The "vhost name" in traceroute is actually the reverse DNS entry for the IP address.  To change what gets shown, change the DNS entry.

Comment: You should also only ever have one PTR record (reverse-dns) per IP address or else bad things can happen with lookups. When I have shared servers, I tend to give the PTR record a very generic name, and only the actual site name if it's got its own dedicated IP.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean the reverse DNS entry should be shown when doing a nslookup on the IP address? Currently, `nslookup [ip]` shows the URI of the hosting company. Not the 'vhost entry' I was talking about. Also, how would it have been set to that in the first place? The IP is shared among many vhosts. So the DNS for the IP must be controlled by the hosting company. I doubt they set that reverse DNS entry...? This is quite confusing :/

Comment: Give us the actual IP address you're talking about, so we can give concrete answers rather than hypothetical ones.

Comment: IP is `203.170.87.97`

Comment: My traceroute to that address shows `rsl-cp1-virtual.syra.net.au` as the last hop.  Can you edit your question with what you get as the output of tracert?

Comment: Never mind. I just realised what stupid thing I was doing to cause this >.<

Comment: OK, now you *have* to share.  <grin>  You never know, it might help the next person.